# Show that $f$ is discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &x \in \mathbb{Q} \\0, &x \in \mathbb{Q}^c - \{{\sqrt{2}}\} \\ -1 & x = \sqrt{2}.\end{cases}$$.

Show that $f$ is discontinuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then either $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c - \{{\sqrt{2}}\}$ or $ x = \sqrt{2}$.

(i) Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. By the density of irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a number $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}^c - \{{\sqrt{2}}\}$ such that $x < x_n < x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{n}$. Applying the squeeze theorem, we get $x_n \rightarrow x$ since $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x) = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{n}) = x$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1$. But since $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}^c - \{{\sqrt{2}}\}, f(x_n) = 0$. Hence $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

(ii) Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c - \{{\sqrt{2}}\}$. By the density of rationals in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a number $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < x_n < x + \frac{1}{n}$. Applying the squeeze theorem, we get $x_n \rightarrow x$ since $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x) = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x + \frac{1}{n}) = x$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$. But since $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}, f(x_n) = 1$. Hence $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

(iii) Suppose $x = \sqrt{2}$. By the density of rationals in $\mathbb{R}$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a number $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{2} < x_n < \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{n}$. Applying the squeeze theorem, we get $x_n \rightarrow \sqrt{2}$ since $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x) = \sqrt{2}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x + \frac{1}{n}) = \sqrt{2}$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = -1$. But since $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}, f(x_n) = 1$. Hence $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: “discontinuous on $\Bbb R$” is ambiguous: does it mean not continuous on $\Bbb R$, or continuous nowhere in $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is close to working.  However, at the moment, all of your

> Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = [\ldots]$

need an explanation, as they don't follow from the previous steps.  (You seem to be using a proof by contradiction, but you never wrote down the assumption that would justify this step)

---

Summarizing my comments:

You are using an implicit assumption that $f$ is continuous at $x$, but this is something you must state in the proof.  One way would be to change the "Hence" line I referenced above to

> If $f$ were continuous at $x$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x) = [\ldots]$

Another way is to assume $f$ is continuous at $x$ before all the cases.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo, it should be -1. I've fixed this now.

Comment: In case (i) when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ I said $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1$ because $x_n \rightarrow x$ so this means that $x_n$ converges to a rational number when $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @Outlier But again, it doesn't follow that $\lim f(x_n) = f(x)$ when $x_n \to x$.  You need to explicitly state your assumption that justifies it.  ( I gave you a hint that you seem to be using contradiction but forgot to write the assumption)

Comment: Ok. Here I am not sure what the assumption is.

Comment: Ok. Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. Assume $f$ is continuous at $x$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x_n) = 1$. Now $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1$ is true since $x_n \rightarrow x \in \mathbb{Q}$. But since $x_n \in \mathbb{Q} - \{\sqrt{2}\}, f(x_n) = 0$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) \neq f(x)$. Therefore $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The squeeze theorem doesn't seem to be the best.  It would almost seem like one avoiding the direct definitions by coming up with a result to hide behind.

If $x_0 \ne \sqrt 2$ then for any $\delta>0$ within the interval $(x_0 -\delta, x_0+\delta)$ there will be point**s** that are rational and that are irrational.  If $y$ is a point that is rational  if $x_0$ is an irrational other than $\sqrt 2$, or $y$ is irrational  but not $\sqrt 2$ if $x_0$ is $\sqrt 2$ or rational.  Then $f(y) = 0$ if $f(x_0) =1$ and $f(y) =1$ if $f(x_0) = 0$.

So $|f(x_0) - f(y)| = 1 > \epsilon$ for  all $\epsilon < 1$.  The the definition of continuous at $x_0$ fails for any $\epsilon < 1$.

Comment: Congrats on 100K! +1

Comment: Ok, yes. I think it might be better to use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains both rational and irrational points, taking $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ in the definition of continuity gives no $\delta$ fulfills it for every point in the domain. Hence $f$ is not continuous at every point.